# Adding variables inside the script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to add variables inside the script tag like this?

```
<script src="page.js" variable1 = "Rome"></script>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need to do that?

Comment: I want to pass the variable to page.js and then access it!

Comment: This is probably a bad idea.

Comment: This one work for me, but I want a short one:

<script type="text/javascript">
var variable1 = "Rome";
</script>
 
<script src="page.js"></script>